# Import Google Reader subscriptions into Flipboard

Tags: import, rss, google

Is there a simple way to import my rss subscriptions from Google Reader(GR) into [Flipboard](http://flipboard.com/)(F). I know i can read the subscriptions in F, but want to really import them into F so i can access it in F after GR will shutdown.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes there is and it is described in an article on the Flipboard web page: "[We’ve Got Your RSS Covered! Save Your Google Reader Feeds Now](http://inside.flipboard.com/2013/03/14/weve-got-your-rss-covered-save-your-google-reader-feeds-now/)".

Basically you just have to choose *Google Reader* in the *Accounts* tab. Once imported, Flipboard will fetch the feeds on its own. So it will also stay when Google has shut down Reader.

Just one more hint:
If you want to save your feeds in a stand-alone file (e.g. for backing up) you could use [Google Takeout](http://www.dataliberation.org/google/reader).

Comment: What if I don't want to give them access to my account?